# Formation of generator matrix for linear block code

Tags: linear-algebra, coding-theory

I am trying to form generator matrix for (15,11) Hamming code as mentioned in the following link http://www.mee.tcd.ie/~ledoyle/TEACHING/12%20-%20error2.pdf Page.no:12.

The problem is **when non-zero bits in the 11 bit input is odd**  *I'm getting expected parity bits*, but **non-zero bits in the 11 bit input is even** *the result of parity bit is 1's complement of expected output*

If anyone knows the way to solve this 1's complement issue, kindly let me know.

Comment: It is difficult to figure out what went wrong. Checking out the slide set is a non-starter- My somewhat educated guess is that the $(15,11)$ Hamming code was defined using a standard (at least of the standards) ordering of the columns, and you try to produce a systematic generator matrix out of that. What then happens is that you cannot do that because the 11th bit is a linear combination of the preceeding ones. In other words, you cannot use position 1 thru 11 for payload. You must use some other set of eleven positions. May be 1 thru 10 and 12?

Comment: The eleventh column of the identity matrix won't appear in the eleventh column of the generator matrix, but that doesn't stop use from finding a generator matrix.